# How to deploy a plotly-dash app on a company internal server so that only company workers can use it?

Tags: python, web-deployment, plotly-dash

I am doing a project for a company where I work. I created a Python Dash app on my work laptop using Jupyter and it works fine. Now I want to deploy the app on the company's local server, so I need all users in our company to be able to view it. But I don't want to use any web-based service (Heroku, etc.) as the data is confidential and sensitive. So, I want it to run from the local server and be accessible by anyone that wants to use it within the company.

What is the way of doing this?

In order to run the app I am using code below.

```py
# Run the app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: [Self host Flask App](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/deploying/#self-hosted-options) might be worth looking into. Dash is based on Flask.

Comment: I suggest a combination of [gunicorn](https://fizzy.cc/deploy-dash-on-server/) with [SSL encryption](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#ssl) turned on and [Basic Auth](https://dash.plotly.com/authentication#basic-auth).

Comment: The accepted answer was provided and explained in this linked duplicate: [How to deploy a Python Dash Application on an internal company server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71860253/how-to-deploy-a-python-dash-application-on-an-internal-company-server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated:

Finally I found a solution to my question above. Basically you can use below code in your terminal:

```
 waitress-serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8080  appname:app.server
```

Here you use your own host and port numbers.

Comment: Is it possible to provide more explanation?

Comment: I am in a similar boat. WOuld love more info here if possible?